# Formula for number of attempts to insert a value into a hash table using linear probing

Tags: hash-tables

Suppose I have the simple hash-probe function and we are using linear probing

(k,i) = (k + i) mod m

Assume that there are 3 keys that need to be inserted(k1,k2,k3).
Is there a formula for the average number of attempts required to insert each of the 3 keys?

I know that the avg. no of attempts to insert k1 = 1, since there is no values in the table yet, so it cannot collide with anything so will always take 1 attempt. However i'm struggling to come up with a formula for k2,k3.

Comment: Continuing with $k2$ looks a promising idea. What is $i$? Is there any information about the "distribution" of $k$ values?

Comment: i is the number of times we have tried to insert the key, so first its 0, if we get a collison, i becomes 1 and so on. I was not given a distrubution of k values apart from that k1 = 0, so i'm just trying to work out a general formula if there even is one without knowing the k values?

Comment: You don't need to know the $k$ values. I'd be surprised if you didn't need to *assume* or *know* something about their distribution.